# Formatting double values ignoring leading zeros in fraction part

Tags: ios, swift, formatting, number-formatting

I want to format the fraction part of double values with 5 digits by ignoring the leading zeros, for example:

0.123456 -> 0.12345

0.00001234567 -> 0.000012345

0.0001234567 -> 0.00012345

how can I do that?

I tried to set the maximum and minimum fraction digits with the number formatter but it didn't give me the result I wanted.

Comment: I am pretty sure you need to write some custom format logic for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use usesSignificantDigits with maximumSignificantDigits from NSNumberFormatter.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumberformatter/1417793-usessignificantdigits

```
let nf = NSNumberFormatter()
nf.usesSignificantDigits = true
nf.maximumSignificantDigits = 5
```

Should do the trick

Comment: Significant digits also includes the integer part so this will not work for values >= 1 (or <= -1).

Comment: Current problem/example was with fractions. And it can be easily adapted to >= 1 (or <= -1) cases by just removing integer part. IMHO it's better than using regex

Comment: Regex has nothing to do with your answer, please update it with a solution that also handles values >= 1

Comment: It doesn't exactly fulfill what I want. But thank you

Comment: @turtleCombat You should make the effort to explain why it doesn't work

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Because it does not produce the outcomes I asked in the question

Comment: I made a mistake when passing the double value, this works.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do that with a regular expression:

```
^\d+\.(0*)\d{1,5}
```

Result:

```
0.00001234567 => 0.000012345
3.7 => 3.7
1.00523 => 1.00523
2.00287638723687263 => 2.0028763
```

Comment: Can you put this as a code? I couldn't get the expected results. I think I'm missing something